# Agda's `rewrite` fails with an error mentioning variable "w"

Tags: agda

I have these definitions (irrelavant ones are removed)

```
open import Agda.Builtin.Nat renaming (Nat to ℕ)

infix 3 _>0
data _>0 : ℕ → Set where
  intro : ∀ n → suc n >0

infix 4 _*>0_
_*>0_ : ∀ {a b} → a >0 → b >0 → a * b >0
intro n *>0 intro m = intro (m + n * suc m)

infix 5 _÷_⟨_⟩
data ℚ : Set where
  _÷_⟨_⟩ : (a b : ℕ) → b >0 → ℚ
```

And I wanted to prove this to be true:

```
open import Agda.Builtin.Equality

div-mul-comm : ∀ a c d → (x : c >0) → (y : d >0) →
               a ÷ c * d ⟨ x *>0 y ⟩ ≡ a ÷ d * c ⟨ y *>0 x ⟩
div-mul-comm a c d x y = ?
```

But whatever I tried I can't prove this, also, the error message is strange.
This is what I've tried:

```
postulate nat-multiply-comm : ∀ a b → a * b ≡ b * a

div-mul-comm a c d x y
  rewrite nat-multiply-comm c d = {!!}
```

Agda says:

> c * d != w of type ℕ
>   when checking that the type
>   (c d w : ℕ) →
>   w ≡ d * c →
>   (a : ℕ) (x : c >0) (y : d >0) →
>   a ÷ w ⟨ x *>0 y ⟩ ≡ a ÷ d * c ⟨ y *>0 x ⟩
>   of the generated with function is well-formed

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): I had to chase missing import statements and fiddle with fixity levels to get the file to parse.

Comment: I think it's already a minimal one since I just used the standard library... Maybe I should use `Agda.Builtin` only. Wait

Comment: It's not **complete** though. I'm still missing `nat-multiply-comm`. Using `+-comm` from the standard library does not yield the error you're reporting.

Comment: I used a `postulate`. I think there shouldn't be more mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that when you rewrite `c * d` to `d * c`, you also need to patch up the proof `x *>0 y` that `c * d >0` into a proof that `d * c >0`.

Personally I would introduce two intermediate lemmas:

```
>0-irrelevant : ∀ a → (p q : a >0) → p ≡ q
```

which allows you to swap proofs that `a >0` around depending on what you need. And

```
div-subst : ∀ a b c → b ≡ c → (p : b >0) (q : c >0) →
            a ÷ b ⟨ p ⟩ ≡ a ÷ c ⟨ q ⟩
```

which allows you to replace the second component of a `ℚ` with an equal value and replace the now obsolete proof `p : b >0` by another one `q : c >0`. `>0-irrelevant` will be useful to prove this second lemma.